# Lambda keeps returning Error: function response: 401 - {"status":"error","message":"401 Unauthorized"}

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a function on AWS lambda with internet gateway and NAT on a VPC, but I keep getting a `Error: function response: 401 - {"status":"error","message":"401 Unauthorized"}`on every request made within the lambda

Comment: First thing: does it really need to be inside a VPC? Second: you said you get a 401 when issuing a call from within your Lambda. Are you sending it to another API Gateway?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be in a VPC. It's saving the data gotten into an RDS in the same VPC

Comment: `GET` request works fine. It has NAT and Internet Gateway.
This only happens with a `POST`

Comment: but you said it gets a 401 when a call is made from within your Lambda function, meaning your function is interacting with something else. Or was that just a typo and  you get a 401 when you call your function through your API Gateway? Would you mind sharing some code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/robophil/c84a2b0d5fa5f3582634418d3a276469

Comment: I'm trying to communicate with an API else where

Comment: I'd say there's no problem with your code then. The API you're trying to authenticate against is private and you are providing invalid credentials.

Comment: The credentials are fine.
I just figured out that my `elastic ip` wasn't whitelisted by the service provider :-)
Thanks for the help